# wordpress multisite remove /sites/{ID}/ automatic upload url

Tags: wordpress, upload, structure, dir, multisite

when using wp multisites it gets messed up pretty fast.
Is there any solution available removing the automatic /sites/{id}/ folder structure?

I'm able to adjust the site-upload-dir within site-settings but it always adds " /sites/{id}/ " to the uploaded file through the media-manager.

Is there any snippet available removing/disabling these extra folder structure?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of it? That's how it keeps the different sites' data separate.

Comment: thanks for asking. the site's data still gets seperated, it is in our custom-named-subfolder which we define through site>settings.
This way we do have a nice name within our uploads/sites folder and it is easier to find the specific page. Instead of looking up the id.

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 4):

First I ended up changing the core in `wp-includes/functions.php` in order to disable the addition:

```
if ( defined( 'MULTISITE' ) )
    $ms_dir = '/sites/' . get_current_blog_id();
else
    $ms_dir = '/' . get_current_blog_id();
```

And one line below that my hack:

```
$ms_dir = '';
```

But after a while I found this [solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/261933/153824) where one can use a hook. Example:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'same_upload_dir' );
function same_upload_dir( array $uploads ) {
    $baseurl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads';
    $basedir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads';
    $subdir = $uploads['subdir'];

    return array(
        'path'    => $basedir . $subdir,
        'url'     => $baseurl . $subdir,
        'subdir'  => $subdir,
        'basedir' => $basedir,
        'baseurl' => $baseurl,
        'error'   => false,
    );
}
```