# Disable WordPress Multisite Modifying Media URL

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I'm using DigitalOcean Spaces to store my static assets. All is working fine, my media library url point to my Spaces (e.g. foobar.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com).

The problem starts when I install multisite, as it's default WordPress behavior to add "sites/xxx" to all sub site's media url (e.g. foobar.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/sites/2). Which of course, my assets are not there, and can't be found.

I've found this link:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307530/remove-multisite-part-from-wordpress-multisite-upload-directory

Which gave me an idea.

I've tried this on functions.php

```php
add_filter('upload_dir', 'multisite_path');

function multisite_path( $param ){
    $path = str_replace('sites/2/', '', $param['path']);
    $url = str_replace('sites/2/', '', $param['url']);
    $param['path'] = $path;
    $param['url'] = $url;

    return $param;
}
```

But it's not working.

If there's a hook to remove "sites/2/" from the url, or any other way to disable this functionality, I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here:

[wordpress multisite remove /sites/{ID}/ automatic upload url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703248/wordpress-multisite-remove-sites-id-automatic-upload-url)

Here's the working code:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', 'same_upload_dir' );
function same_upload_dir( array $uploads ) {
    $baseurl = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/uploads';
    $basedir = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads';
    $subdir = $uploads['subdir'];

    return array(
        'path'    => $basedir . $subdir,
        'url'     => $baseurl . $subdir,
        'subdir'  => $subdir,
        'basedir' => $basedir,
        'baseurl' => $baseurl,
        'error'   => false,
    );
}
```